# PostgreSQL: Concurrent inserts on table with two unique constraints with ON CONFLICT still conflict

Tags: postgresql, index, unique-constraint

I have the following schema:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
CREATE TABLE foo (bar JSONB UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_hash ON foo (digest(bar::text, 'sha256'));
```

Note that there are two unique constraints. The reason for this is that `foo.bar` should be unique but large JSONB values exceed the BTree max width (basically the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63185204/2891835)). I'm migrating from the index on the JSONB column to the expression index on the hash so currently both constraints are there.

If I run multiple inserts in parallel via:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

psql -c "TRUNCATE foo"
for i in {1..2}
do
  psql -c " \
      INSERT INTO foo(bar) \
      VALUES ('{\"hi\":\"bye\"}') \
      ON CONFLICT (digest(bar::text, 'sha256')) DO NOTHING \
  " &
done

wait
```

I'll get:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_bar_key"
DETAIL:  Key (bar)=({"hi": "bye"}) already exists.
```

How is this possible? My expectation is that the expression index would be a match and so we'd `DO NOTHING` but instead we're trying to insert and hitting the other unique constraint (or something).

My only random guess is that Postgres is evaluating the expression index for both inserts, finding no conflict (because the table is empty), inserting the first one, and then failing to insert the second one but I have no idea how I'd verify that.

**Note**: Because our resolution is `DO NOTHING` we don't have to specify the constraint and *that* works without error but I'd still like to understand what's going on.

Comment: The conflict is on the primary key, not on the `unique_hash` constraint

Comment: I find a primary key on a JSON column extremely strange to be honest

Comment: Ah, yes, I know the conflict is on the primary key. My question is _why_ does this conflict happen? If I don't run these queries concurrently then there is no conflict on the primary key. Postgres sees that the expression index has a conflict and properly does nothing. If I run them concurrently then _sometimes_ there is a conflict on the primary key. I don't obviously see anything in the docs that would explain this.

Comment: Also, yeah, the primary key on the JSONB column may be strange but that's what we've got haha. And this phenomenon happens if the column is, for instance, TEXT instead so I'd still like to understand the underlying Postgres-insertion-conflict-resolution-ordering-whatever that causes these errors occasionally.

Comment: If you specify a constraint for the `on conflict` clause only **that** constraint is checked. If you have a violation of any other constraint the INSERT still fails.

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. My question would be - how would the conflict clause above be checked and succeed but have the other one fail? The hashes of these two JSONB values are seemingly equal. If I don't run these concurrently everything's fine so I think the constraint/conflict clause do exactly what they're supposed to.

Is it then just Postgres checking the specified constraint for both inserts, both succeed (because no row is present in the table), one inserts and succeeds, and then the second inserts and fails? I was hoping they'd be "more atomic".